# Bootstrap - Centering textfields

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day! In my log in form, I want my text fields to put it in to center using bootstrap. I already used `class="form-inline justify-content-center"` but it isn't working.

Code:

```
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background: #1b4d32;">
        <form role="form" method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>login/login_submit" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <p id="sign-lbl" style="text-align: center">Please enter your username and<br/>
            password to login.</p><br/><br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" style="border-radius: 25px;">
                </div>
            </div><br/><br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" style="border-radius: 25px;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/><br/>
            <span class="button-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" checked="checked" class="hidden">
                <a class="btn" data-color="info">Stay Signed In</a>
                <a href="<?=base_url()?>login/forgotpassword" class="btn btn-link pull-right">Forgot Password?</a>
            </span>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Sign In">
                </div>
            </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
 </div>
```

So far this is my output:

https://prnt.sc/h675qg / https://jsfiddle.net/kf2c8trp/

Thank you very much

Comment: No need to tag this with javascript and jquery...

Comment: The bootstrap default css is completely missing from your fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this code to your CSS:

```
form {
   text-align:center;
}
```

or as @Connum said, use `text-center` of bootstrap classes. Read more [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/typography/#text-alignment)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use bootstrap's default classes instead of adding this custom CSS just for this?

Comment: @Connum sure, but i think it's not a complicated CSS to add :) he can also use text-center

Answer (score 0):

After adding the bootstrap css file to your fiddle and the class `text-center` to the form, your inputs are being displayed centered: https://jsfiddle.net/kf2c8trp/4/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background: #1b4d32;">
            <form role="form" method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>login/login_submit" class="form-inline justify-content-center text-center">
                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                <p id="sign-lbl" style="text-align: center">Please enter your username and<br/>
                password to login.</p><br/><br/>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" style="border-radius: 25px;">
                    </div>
                </div><br/><br/>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" style="border-radius: 25px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/><br/>
                <span class="button-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" checked="checked" class="hidden">
                    <a class="btn" data-color="info">Stay Signed In</a>
                    <a href="<?=base_url()?>login/forgotpassword" class="btn btn-link pull-right">Forgot Password?</a>
                </span>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Sign In">
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: am gonna also suggest this class in my anwser but you was faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are doing a lot of things wrong. Trying to create space with `<br/>` when you should be using margin or padding is not really cool :). Also, Inline styling is highly discouraged and Justify-content-centre work with flexboxes. That being said check-out the working example below, I have changed some of your bootstrap class and add few scss  link below:

`<div class=" col-xs-12 container" >
            <form class="col-xs-12" role="form" method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>login/login_submit" >
                <p id="sign-lbl">Please enter your username and<br/>
                password to login.</p>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 form-group">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                </div><br/><br/>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 form-group">
                    <div>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="button-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" checked="checked" class="hidden">
                    <a class="btn" data-color="info">Stay Signed In</a>
                    <a href="<?=base_url()?>login/forgotpassword" class="btn btn-link pull-right">Forgot Password?</a>
                </span>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 ">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Sign In">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>`

[Check out the updated link](https://jsfiddle.net/sholeman/kf2c8trp/7/)